# Laravel group by with select all column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way on laravel eloquent to query like this:

```
select users.* from users group by name
```

to implement it on code:

```
Users::select('name')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Now I need to get other details (columns) of the user. Is there a way to query without aggregating every column  on the model, this will not work:

```
Users::select('users.*')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working;

```
Users::select('users.*')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

just make sure your model name. You don't have to write class name, and if model name is User then change to

```
User::groupBy('name')->get();
```

Don't forget to import the model at the top according to your folder structure `use App\User;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Users::groupBy('name')->get();
```

Since laravel is independent of the type of database you use, so your query should be eloquent.
For more details read this official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections)